# Xamarin.Forms setting IsEnable to true not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms and I am trying to use disable a button and then enable it when the button action is finished, when I disable it, the button does in fact become disabled, but when I enable it, its still disabled, what am I doing wrong? Here is my full method:

```
private void OnCameraScan(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScanLicence.IsEnabled = false;

    var barcodeScanView = new ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingScannerView
    {
        HeightRequest = 200
    };

    ScannerWrapper.HeightRequest = 200;
    ScannerWrapper.IsVisible = true;


    var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
    {
        TryHarder = true,
        CameraResolutionSelector = HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate,
        PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.PDF_417 },
    };

    barcodeScanView.OnScanResult += (result) =>
    {
        barcodeScanView.IsScanning = false;

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        var data = result.Text.Split('\n');

        foreach (var line in data)
        {

            if (line.Length > 3)
            {
                var code = line.Substring(0, 3);
                var value = line.Substring(3);

                Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    switch (code)
                    {
                        case "DCT":
                            userClass.Customer_Name = value.Trim();
                            Customer_Name.Text = value.Trim();
                            break;
                        case "DCS":
                            userClass.Customer_LName = value.Trim();
                            Customer_LName.Text = value.Trim();
                            break;
                        case "DAI":
                            userClass.City = value.Trim();
                            City.Text = value.Trim();
                            break;
                        case "DAG":
                            userClass.Address1 = value.Trim();
                            Address1.Text = value.Trim();
                            break;
                        case "DAK":
                            userClass.Zip = value.Trim();
                            Zip.Text = value.Trim();
                            break;
                    }

                });


            }
        }

        ScanLicence.IsEnabled = true;


    };

    barcodeScanView.Options = options;
    barcodeScanView.IsScanning = true;

    ScannerWrapper.Children.Add(barcodeScanView);

}
```

The button in question is `ScanLicence`.

```
<Button x:Name="ScanLicence" Text="Scan Licence" Clicked="OnCameraScan" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" WidthRequest="50" />
```

This is for an iOS application.

Comment: is `OnScanResult` being called? because the only explanation would be you are not reaching `ScanLicence.IsEnabled = true;`

Comment: Yes it...I wrapped it in this: Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => and it works now.

Comment: If question is answered and issue is resolved, please add an answer with the solution and accept it. (You can accept your own answers). Doing this would keep potentially helpful people from looking at this question thinking it still needs an answer and save these helpful folks some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cast the object which invokes the event to "Button" and then disable it. At the end of your code you could have something like this:

```
// Safe casting to Button instance.
Button button = sender as Button;

// Make sure the cast didn't return a null value
if(button == null) return;

// Set enable to true
button.IsEnabled = true; // You can also use button.IsEnabled = !button.IsEnabled
```

Make sure that you don't have any kind of binding of the button, it may be ignoring property assigment in code behind.